# Calculating the gamma value of x without the math module globally?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider an input of type integer which it's y-value shall be calculated at that x-coordinate (of the input), e.g. for the input 5, the output shall be 24. Gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function

My example code was:

```
from math import gamma as gf

#[...]
print(gf(x))
```

It works perfectly as it is, however as the programm itself is pretty huge and I only need the gamma import once, I don't want to import the module globally - is there any other option to calculate the gamma function in this context without explicitly importing the math.gamma module in the top of my import line, i.e. is there a short version inside the code syntax to calculate the gamme value of x?

Comment: What is the benefit of not importing it at the top of the file? It's going to be imported anyway. If you're only using it in one place then it would probably make more sense to `import math` at the top and then call `math.gamma`, so that it's more obvious what function is being called when you call it. But generally it is good practice (and specified in PEP 8) to declare imports at the top of the file, not within functions.

Comment: @kaya3 It doesn't flood the code if I only need to use it once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact a built-in function which you can use, called `__import__()`. Syntax of this function: `__import__ (name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])` (see more [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/__import__.html)).

Hence your code could be shorten to a sweet one-liner.
Given `x = 5`:

```
ga_val = __import__('math', globals(), locals(), [], 0).gamma(x)
```

Output: `24.0` with ga_val being type `float`.

---

As to suggestion by @kaya3 my answer could be shorten to just:

```
ga_val = __import__('math').gamma(x)
```

Comment: Short solution! It doesn't import the math module globally -> accepted.

Comment: This can be shortened to `__import__('math').gamma(x)`.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm getting code-golf vibes. Thanks a lot, I edited my reply.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the Gamma function and you're only applying it to integers?  `Γ(x) = (x - 1)! = math.fact(x - 1)` when `x` is a positive integer.

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest it's only being applied to integers; but replacing `math.gamma` with `math.fact` doesn't seem to address any issue to do with how the `math` module gets imported, which is what the question is about.

Comment: The first sentence.  "Consider an input of type integer." is the very first sentence.

Comment: +1 A good solution! Though it dodges the solution as I would need to import the math module globally as well.

Comment: Or just write factorial yourself.  Four lines of python.